# Linker does not recognize (generated) methods if the count of methods is high enough

Tags: c, linker, code-generation

I have a weird problem with the linker (appears with different compilers).

I'm genreating kernels like that:

```
inline void doSomething3() {
  #pragma omp for simd nowait schedule(static, chunkSize)
  for (int i = 0; i < size_mat; ++i) {
    matrix[i] +=
            buffer->threadedData[1].matr[i]
        +   buffer->threadedData[2].matr[i];
    buffer->threadedData[1].matr[i] = 0.0;
    buffer->threadedData[2].matr[i] = 0.0;
  }
```

This is an example for 3 threads where the buffers of thread 1 and 2 are added up to another buffer. But the content of the kernel is not the important part.

Basically, I'm generating lets say 16 of such kernels with names
doSomething2(), doSomething3(), doSomething4() and so on. Each are different in the number of arrays they sum up.
These kernels are generated via boost and preprocessor directives. And this generation works fine (as one can check in the output of the preprocessor).

Now, it looks like that the linker gets into trouble when increasing the number of kernels at some point.

Usually, I'm generating 16 kernels (times 8 since I have different things to sumup). This works fine for Intel compiler and Clang. GCC and GCC on 32 bit do not accept that many kernels. I get a linker error there (even if the kernels are correctly generated) and the maximum number is 8 for GCC. When switching to debug mode, the number is even smaller (in debug mode also for Clang and Intel, 16 is not possible). So far, so strange.

```
/opt/gcc/11.2.0/linux70_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/my.dir/omp_sumUp/omp_sumUp.c.o: in function `doSomething_matrix':
omp_sumUp.c:(.text+0xedb1): undefined reference to 'doSomething16'
/opt/gcc/11.2.0/linux70_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: omp_sumUp.c:(.text+0x110b1): undefined reference to 'doSomething13'
/opt/gcc/11.2.0/linux70_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: omp_sumUp.c:(.text+0x110c9): undefined reference to 'doSomething14'
/opt/gcc/11.2.0/linux70_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: omp_sumUp.c:(.text+0x110e1): undefined reference to 'doSomething15'
```

Now, a colleague changed some part in the code in another place and this also changed the number of kernels which can be treated by the linker. WTF?

Originally, I expected the generation of the kernels to be the problem, but as mentioned, there everything works fine. The compiler did also his job as I could see the kernels in the optimization report. So, the linker remains.

Does anybody have a clue what the issue of the linker is (overflow on number of methods?) and how to solve it?

Comment: Please [edit] and show the verbatim error log.

Comment: No ideas on the topic?